# Fails to get ini file value

Tags: delphi, ini

Im try get a value form a ini file. The ini file is:

```
[Database]
User=root
Pssword=lalalala
Server=localhost
Name=Prueba
```

And my code procedure to read is:

```
procedure testManejoIniFile();
var
  iniFile: TIniFile;
  user: String;
begin
  {Abro el archivo ini}
  iniFile := TIniFile.Create('config.ini');
  user := iniFile.ReadString('Database','User','Algo anda mal...');
  iniFile.Free;
  WriteLn(user);
end;
```

The cli program that invokes the procedure is:

```
WriteLn('El usuario para la base de datos es:');
testManejoIniFile();
ReadLn;
```

The cli always returns:

> El usuario para la base de datos es: 
>  Algo anda mal...

Any ideas ?.

Comment: Where does config.ini reside in relationship to the program?

Comment: TIniFile.Create looks for the ini file in the windows folder... is this where you've located it?  Otherwise, you could maybe use TINIFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName) + 'config.ini');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not specifically saying where `TIniFile.Create` should look for the `config.ini` file, so it's looking in the Windows directory by default and not finding it, and returning the default value you said it should return.

You need to specify the location of the `config.ini` file. If it's in the same folder as your application, you can get the path from either `ParamStr(0)` or `Application.ExeName` using `ExtractFilePath` like this (I've added a `try..finally` to guard against exceptions, and moved the `WriteLn` so that it's only called if the `ReadString` succeeds):

```
procedure testManejoIniFile();
var
  iniFile: TIniFile;
  user: String;
  Path: string;
begin
  {Abro el archivo ini}
  Path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)); // Or Application.ExeName
  iniFile := TIniFile.Create(Path + 'config.ini');
  try
    user := iniFile.ReadString('Database','User','Algo anda mal...');
    WriteLn(user);
  finally
    iniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ken is correct. I just wanted to add that you should ALWAYS specify the full path to a file, because things such as an common dialog (open and save) will change the Current Directory of the app.